# How to format into single date_time from mixed date_times(as factor)

Tags: r

I have column as date (factor data type) with mixed date_times as a factor

```
date
2014-12-30 12:00:00
30-12-2014 12:00:00
12/30/2014 12:00:00 
30-Dec-2014 12:00:00
```

How to format above date-time with R format
like `2014-12-30 12:00:00`

I have tried

```
library(anytime)
anytime(as.factor("df$date"))
```

Comment: Why not just `anytime(df$date)`? What's up with the `as.factor` and the quotes?

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102462/r-changing-date-format-in-one-column-that-contains-two-date-formats/42102572 - where Dirk discusses how ddmmyy and mmddyy in the same data is not going to play nicely. My answer there might be helpful too.

Comment: I have tried but throwing error as : Error in inherits(x, "POSIXt") : object 'df' not found

Comment: Then your data set isn't called `df`, eh? What the name of your data set?

Comment: x <- c("2014-12-30 12:00:00",
       "30-12-2014 12:00:00",
       "12/30/2014 12:00:00",
       "30-Dec-2014 12:00:00" )

Comment: library(anytime)
anytime(x,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

Comment: Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

Comment: just do `anytime(x)`

Comment: You are passing a format into the timezone parameter. You should really read the docs. It's only one function.