# Convert different date-time-formats at once (strptime)

Tags: r, datetime, strptime

Hi :) I have a column of my data.frame which contains dates in two formats. Here is an short minimal example:

```
D = data.frame(dates = c("3/31/2016", "01.12.2015"))

       dates
1 3/31/2016
2 01.12.2015
```

With the nice function `strptime` I can easily get date-times for each format:

```
D$date1 <- strptime(D$dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
D$date2 <- strptime(D$dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

I already managed a workaround with:

```
D$date12 <- do.call(pmin, c(D[c("date1","date2")], na.rm=TRUE) )
```

To achieve this:

```
       dates      date1      date2     date12
1  3/31/2016 2016-03-31       <NA> 2016-03-31
2 01.12.2015       <NA> 2015-12-01 2015-12-01
```

Is there are more sophisticated way to do this transformation (from dates to date12) at once?

Regards

Comment: You can just nest each of your calls and run it all in one block - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102462/r-changing-date-format-in-one-column-that-contains-two-date-formats/42102572 - or potentially adapt the `anytime` or `lubridate` options from that question.

Comment: I read about anytime before, but my systems prevents me from installing and using this package; I first have to figure out why ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `anytime` package.

```
library(anytime)
anytime::addFormats("%d.%m.%Y")
anydate(D$dates)
```

Note that the argument in `anydate` has to be a vector, so just select the coloumn `dates`.

Or use `lubridate`

```
parse_date_time(D$dates, c("mdy", "dmy"))
```

Comment: `anytime` does not support mixing dmy and mdy by default. They are ambiguous at best and will give an incorrect answer in this case unless you add other formats explicitly - see the author's comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104221/496803